# sql consulta tablas relacionadas

Tags: sql

tengo dos tablas en la base de datos. Una con aficionados y otra con equipos. En la tabla aficionados hay un campo que es el equipo al que siguen.

Necesito una unica consulta que me devuelva todos los campos de la tabla equipos y ademas me diga el numero de seguidores para cada equipo.

```
SELECT * FROM equipos

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM aficionados WHERE id_equipo = $id_equipo
```

De esta manera lo obtendría en dos consultas, pero como podría hacerlo en una sola?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sin saber qué campos tiene tu tabla equipo (y considerando que pueden ser muchos campos o que puedas añadir campos a futuro) la manera más flexible es con una tabla derivada:

```
SELECT equipos.*,
       afc.conteo
FROM equipos 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id_equipo, 
                  count(*) conteo 
           FROM aficionados 
           GROUP BY id_equipo) afc ON equipos.id = afc.id_equipo
```

Ahora, si lo importante fuesen sólo un puñado de campos (por ejemplo, el nombre y el país del equipo) sería más elegante hacer

```
SELECT equipos.id,
       equipos.nombre,
       equipos.pais,
       count(*) as conteo
FROM equipos 
LEFT JOIN aficionados ON equipos.id = aficionados.id_equipo
GROUP BY equipos.id, equipos.nombre, equipos.pais
```

Comment: Gracias. Funciona, el único problema es que a los equipos que no tienen seguidores aparecen con un conteo de 1.

Comment: @tonio marca la respuesta y así ayudarás al grupo

Comment: @tonio aparecen con resultado 1 en la segunda query, supongo. En la primera debieran salir en cambio valores NULL

Comment: coloca un isnull(count(*), 0) de esa manera te deberia de salir 0 cuando no tenga datos en la tabla de aficionados, aun que se me hacer raro que salga 1, deberia de salir null ya que es un left outer join

Answer (score 3):

Otra manera, a parte de la de amenadiel, seria meter tu segunda consulta en el `select` de la primera:

```
SELECT 
    E.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Aficionados WHERE id_equipo = $id_equipo) AS TOTAL 
FROM 
    Equipos as E
```

Comment: Y sin meter la variable `$id_equipo` que parece venir de PHP, también podría usarse `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Aficionados WHERE id_equipo = E.id)`, pero esto si no me equivoco invoca una subconsulta por cada fila.

Comment: Gracias a los dos. Con la modificacion de amenadiel obtengo los resultados tal y como yo buscaba.

Comment: @tonio pues recuerda marcar la de amenadiel como la correcta pulsando el "check" debajo de la puntuacion de la respuesta^^